# Ajax JQuery request doesn't get sent

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

It used to work fine, and I don't remember changing anything in these files, but now nothing happens when I click on submit form. What may cause the problem?

**Snippet:**

```js
// And here's the ajax request file *auth_ajax.js*:

$(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'check_user.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        if (response['found'] === 'true') {
          location.href = 'index.php';
        } else {
          alert('Incorrect username or password');
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Here's my php file: -->

<h1 id="header">Enter your data here</h1>
<form>
  <label for="login">Login</label>
  <input type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Enter your login here" required><br>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What errors do you see int the console and network tab of the debugger?

Answer (score -1):

This route work?

```
url: 'check_user.php',
```

Try yourDomain/check_user.php, check your directory  for a real path